# Transitioning to a ViewController leaves the navigation bar of the previous view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller, catransition

I want the programmatically navigate to a ViewController with this kind of transitioning that I got from stackoverflow.

```
  CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
  transition.duration = .45;
  transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
  transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
  self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  AddDeviceViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddDeviceViewController"];
  self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

But when it transitions to the View, the navigation bar from the previous view stays. How can I make the Navigation Bar of the transitioned View appear instead of the previous one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` in your `AddDeviceViewController`. In `viewWillAppear` hide `navigation bar` and in `viewWillDisappear` show `navigation bar`. This mechanism only hide navigation bar for `AddDeviceViewController`. Something like,

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
 }

 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

       self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
 }
```

Comment: then once try to hide `navigationbar` in `viewDidDisAppear` of `previous view cotroller`!

Comment: Thanks for the help! The logic was very straight forward.